# One-liner to create a list of iterating sequences?

Tags: r, list, iteration, lapply, replicate

I need to create a list of sequences that always goes back to the first digit in the sequence. I've written the code below but it seems clunky. Is there a solution that uses fewer characters?

```r
(i = seq(1, 24, by = 3))
#> [1]  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22
(i_list = purrr::map(i, ~c(.:(. + 2), .)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> ...
```

Edit: here's a way with `lapply()`. Not sure why this is getting downvotes, any advice on how to improve the question welcome!

```r
(i_list = lapply(i, function(x) c(x:(x+2), x)))
```

I was wondering if there's a way with `replicate()` so have added that tag.

Comment: your code fits on one line and is 42 characters. how is that clunky?

Comment: I was wondering if there's a 1 liner.

Answer (score 2):

In matrix, rather than list form, theres:

`cbind(matrix(1:24, ncol=3,byrow=TRUE),seq(1, 24, by = 3))`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    1
[2,]    4    5    6    4
[3,]    7    8    9    7
[4,]   10   11   12   10
[5,]   13   14   15   13
[6,]   16   17   18   16
[7,]   19   20   21   19
[8,]   22   23   24   22
```

and then you'd iterate over rows of the matrix instead of elements of the list.

Or if you are into code golf:

```
> seq(1,24,by=3) + t(matrix(c(0,1,2,0),ncol=8,nrow=4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    1
[2,]    4    5    6    4
[3,]    7    8    9    7
[4,]   10   11   12   10
...
```

but then how much work do you put into constructing the RHS of the `+` in this case? How is your question parameterised?

This depends on `i` having a regular pattern (with some adjustment for step size), it doesn't work for arbitrary `i` sequences.